# Railroad Power lines interfering with Heart rate Monitor

Tags: heart-rate

I have two heart rate monitor chest straps from Sigma and one from Garmin. Everytime I pass close by a trainline the numbers on my HR-Display go bananas. I'm about to go insane because of this, is there anything to do against this? Buy something new? Or throw it all in the bin..

Comment: Can you be more specific about the model of heart rate monitors you have? Do you know what communication methods they use, like ANT+, Bluetooth, or some other proprietary protocol. I used to have similar problems with an old wireless speedometer when waiting at traffic lights.  But I haven't had any problems with my ANT+ HRM or speed/cadence monitors.

Comment: About all you can do is try to get the sensor and receiver closer to each other.  A different monitor might be better in this situation or might be worse.

Comment: Not much you can do but avoid trainlines short of wrapping yourself in a faraday cage or something.

Comment: I have encountered this with a blue tooth HRM. Yes, it messes with the log. The only thing you can do is avoid areas with high electrical power, since its the actual heart beat signal that's getting distorted.

Comment: Default heart monitor for the Sigma Rox 10.0 (smashed one of them already) and default heart monitor for the Garmin Edge 520 (recently bought & 10x more Problems). So a wrist Heart rate meter will have the same problems?

Comment: I've had similar trouble with HR-straps and sensors from Sigma. They don't follow the ANT+ protocol and showed no or strange values in a radius of 5-7km around a strong local long wave radio transmitter. No trouble with ANT+ sensors at the same location where I pass along quite often.

Comment: Your problem comes from electrical interference with the heart rate sensor. If you have to have a solution, switch to a heart rate monitor that uses an optical sensor. Many of the wristwatch type heart rate monitors use optical sensors.

Comment: That could have been an answer.. ty

Comment: Worth noting that optical heart rate sensors are usually much less accurate than electrically based monitors. At least from what I've heard.

Comment: That's what I just read after researching them. Even electrical chest straps are up to 5 beats off. Looks like it's all garbage.

Comment: I think that they really go for ease of use over trying to get super accurate. 5 BPM error when your hear rate is 150 BPM is really only off by about 3.3%. Not a huge amount of error. Unless you want to start dealing with using medical grade sticky patches to ensure good contact every time you ride, and spending much more money, then you probably aren't going to be able to get much more accuracy.

Comment: My max is 185. And there's a world of difference between maxing out at 175 or 180 during Intervals. 175 is normal. 180 means throwing up all over my garmin and handlebars before I'm even finished.

Comment: Yes, optical is less accurate than electrical, but WAY less sensitive to electrical noise. Both types are sensitive to movement noise.

Comment: @AzulShiva if you are throwing up before you even hit you max I think you have bigger problems than your HRM.

Comment: If you hit your max while cycling you did not hit your max. You should not be able to hit your max while cycling. Ever. Unless you're suffering from hyperthermia or getting a heart attack of course, then it's justified. Your max is your absolute highest possible, if you hit your max regularly you are training waaaaaaay below your zones.

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm... I smell a science project!  If the field is really strong be aware that optical may not work either because the chips/wireless probably aren't shielded anyway. Assuming you don't need laps for training, you could try hitting your lap button so at least you know when the event happens. I suppose you *could* try an experiment by taping aluminum foil to your chest covering the monitor pickups but not the wireless unit. That might tell you if the shielding issue is in the leads as I suspect or in the main unit that picks up the wireless. Ask yourself if the speed/cadence monitors wireless signals are being received to indicate whether an optical monitor might work.